# Integer programming problem

Tags: integer-programming

I have an integer optimization problem with a non-linear function ($F(X)$) in the objective and one of the constraints.
$F(X)=x_n^{i,j}\Big[\sum\limits_{\forall s\neq i}\sum\limits_{\forall m\in\mathcal{S}_s}x^{s,m}_{n}+x_n^{i,j}\Big]$,  where $X$ is binary.

If I solve this integer problem, easily I can linearize $F(X$be) due to the binary nature of $X$.
On the other hand, since the integer problems are NP-hard, I should relax this problem and solve a continuous problem.
But when I relax $X$, $F(X)$ could not be linearized by the same way in integer problem. 
Therefore, the relaxed optimization problem becomes a non-linear problem and this increases the computation complexity.
I was wondering if there is any way to linearize or approximate $F(X)$?
As another question, if I use Taylor first order approximation, should be the problem feasible at the initial point?

Comment: The Taylor series question is interesting but should probably be asked as a separate question. It's best to ask multiple questions each with their own (narrow) scope rather than to have multi-part questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to linearize $F(X)$, but at the cost of many more binary variables.

Let $x_n^{i,j,s,m} = 1$ if $x_n^{i,j}=x_n^{s,m}=1$ and $=0$ otherwise. Enforce this definition with the following constraints:

$$\begin{align}
x_n^{i,j,s,m} & \ge x_n^{i,j} + x_n^{s,m} - 1\\
x_n^{i,j,s,m} & \le x_n^{i,j} \\
x_n^{i,j,s,m} & \le x_n^{s,m} \\
x_n^{i,j,s,m} & \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$

Now replace $F(X)$ with 
$$\sum_{s\ne i} \sum_{m\in \mathcal{S}_s} x_n^{i,j,s,m} + x_n^{i,j}.$$
(The second term comes from the fact that $\left(x_n^{i,j}\right)^2 = x_n^{i,j}$ since $x_n^{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$.)

Comment: Thanks. originally $X$ is a binary variable. So, I can linearize $F(X)$ easily.  But, I want to relax $X$.

Comment: Relax $X$ how? More importantly, why? It seems you are worried about the NP-hardness of your ILP. But CPLEX and Gurobi eat NP-hard problems for breakfast; you shouldn't over-think it. Have you tried just giving your ILP to CPLEX or Gurobi? They will do the relaxations for you within the branch-and-bound (or -cut) scheme; you don't need to do that part explicitly.

Comment: I am going to write a research paper. I want to relax $X$, after that using rounding techniques, propose a heuristic algorithm. Anyway, I really thank you for your answer.

Comment: Furthermore, to optimally solve the problem, I use PyscipOpt solver in python.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are trying to do, then. Are you saying you want a linear reformulation of $F(X)$ that is exactly equal to the original formulation of $F(X)$ when $X$ is relaxed to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: I don’t know for sure, but I sort of doubt that’s possible.